# Get reference to element nested within another element

Tags: javascript

How do I go about getting a reference to an element nested inside another element I can find by `getElementByID()`?

I have this so far:

```
<table>
  <tr id="templateRow" style="display: none;">
    <td><input    name="f_name[]"         type="text"></td>
    <td><textarea name="f_description[]"  rows="4"></textarea></td>
    <td><input    name="f_category[]"     type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and have some JS that adds in copies of that to build out the table (removing the id and style attributes as I go).

Assuming I have a reference to the `<tr>`, how do I reference the input named `f_name[]` within that table row?

---

Background: For the moment I have temporary id's on the nested elements, removing them too as I go. The tricky situation I have is that I have a function that adds 1 row (and returns a reference to it), and another function that adds multiple rows (calling the `addOneRow` function) .. and I want the `addManyRows` function to end up setting the focus on the first row added.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#templateRow input[name="f_name[]"]');`

Comment: (and yes, I'll refactor to use `<template>` soon enough)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Element#querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) method and where use [attribute equals selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to get based on the attribute.

```
tr.querySelector('td input[name="f_name[]"]')
```

```js
var tr = document.getElementById('templateRow');

tr.querySelector('td input[name="f_name[]"]').style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="templateRow" style="">
    <td>
      <input name="f_name[]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <textarea name="f_description[]" rows="4"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="f_category[]" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can it be done without JQuery? I'm keeping various overheads low.

Answer (score 1):

In any reasonably recent browser, you can use the [`querySelector` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to query for children of the element.

### Example:

```js
var templateRow = document.getElementById('templateRow');

var f_name = templateRow.querySelector('[name="f_name[]"]');
var f_description = templateRow.querySelector('[name="f_description[]"]');
var f_category = templateRow.querySelector('[name="f_category[]"]');

console.log(f_name.outerHTML);
console.log(f_description.outerHTML);
console.log(f_category.outerHTML);
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="templateRow" style="display: none;">
  <td><input    name="f_name[]"         type="text"></td>
  <td><textarea name="f_description[]"  rows="4"></textarea></td>
  <td><input    name="f_category[]"     type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect. Tested with `var first = addOneRow(); addOneRow();addOneRow();addOneRow(); first.querySelector('[name="f_name[]"]').select();` and four rows added, with the first f_name input selected =)